# Chef process with Artifactory

Tags: chef-infra, artifactory

I have read [this tutorial](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Chef+Cookbook+Repositories) about setting Chef repositories in Artifactory ("my own" from Git and official Chef supermarket - two remotes).

Everything works fine, but I don't really understand, how to "pin" it with Chef. I know that you can use ChefDK to easy install cookbooks locally and push them to repository. My question is about end-users: how they can use this virtual Chef repository to easy use cookbooks?

I mean, end-user should run command like:
`chef-client -j params.json`, where it has run_lists or `chef-client -o "recipe[my-cookbook]"` directly. With chef-server this cookbook would be downloaded automatically from server, client has no need to download it manually. How does it work with artifactory, without server (`-z` / `--local` option)? Can I somehow set (`client.rb`?) URL to automatically download cookbooks from repo?

If not, how should I configure chef-server to automatically use cookbooks from Artifactory?

Comment: Did you look at the instruction for working with Chef knife and Artifactory - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Chef+Cookbook+Repositories ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef server and chef-client don't talk to artifactory at all, it is only a replacement for running a private Supermarket for internal use. You would still use Berks or the policyfile system to upload to your Chef Server as per normal.

Comment: And what with non-server client? I guess you can't really use cookbooks straight from artifactory, yes?

Comment: Same thing, it's still the same as it was before just with Artifactory instead of Supermarket. You would normally use `berks vendor` or `chef export` to generate the input files for chef-solo.

Comment: Ok then, I guess that answers my question. Thank you.